# Passing button value as command parameter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a calculator style grid. How can I pass the text of the button as a Command Parameter in Xamarin Forms:

CONTENT RESOURCE

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="PhoneKeys" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference contactsListView}, Path=BindingContext.TapCommand1}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="Pass Button Text"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

GRID LAYOUT

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="6" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="7" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="8" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="9" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="*" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="#" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" />
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible this way. You will have to define your `CommandParameter` on your `Button` itself or have some bindable object behind your `Button` that has a property you can bind to.

Comment: Why not just write all command parameters? As you did that already with Text property. It will take less time than trying to come up with answer how to make it with style. But I think if you write in <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/> it should pass whole Button. And if you write <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Text}"/>, it should pass text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax to get property of control **"{x:Reference myButton}"**
You can send self button reference to get complete button object

**Style**

```
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Reference myButton}" />
```

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" Text="#" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" />
```

Define button name of each button and get the object reference of that button.

```
public ICommand TapCommand1 => new Command((obj) =>
{
        var button = obj as Button;
        var text = button.Text;
});
```

> OR Best way to define command parameter in each button with every button name

```
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Style="{StaticResource PhoneKeys}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference myButton}" Text="#" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" />
```